# Kendo TreeView Server Side Binding Select First Parent Child Node

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am currently using a Kendo Treeview in my MVC application and binding it to my Model property which is a List type that gets built from a controller. The binding works perfectly with the BindTo Method.

What I am trying to do either client side or server side, is to take the First Child of the First parent and apply the css k-state-selected when it loads on the page (or another way to do this). However I am not sure what event to put my logic in. I have tried to use $(document).ready however the treeview object is not yet defined at that point.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slump's suggestion of using the dataBound is a good one, but unfortunately won't apply for what you're trying to accomplish here.

The issue is that your control is server-side bounded, so the HTML is going to render before the page is completely loaded, thus you won't be able to snatch up an instance of the object you need.

If you place *document ready* in a script tag at the BOTTOM of the page, rather than the TOP, you should be able to correctly retrieve the object.

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to place your logic in the **dataBound** event. Putting your logic in the dataBound event of the tree view will ensure the view is fully rendered on the page and that you will have access to all of it's elements. They discuss a similar situation for the Kendo Grid View [here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/general-discussions/knowing-when-a-kendo-widget-is-rendered.aspx). See the following example:

```
<div id="treeview"></div>

<script>
    $('#treeview').kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: [
            {
                text: 'foo',
                items: [
                    { text: 'bar' }
                ]
            }
        ],
        dataBound: function (e) {
            //get the tree view...
            var treeview = $('#treeview').data('kendoTreeView');

            //get first parent...
            var parentNode = treeview.dataSource.view()[0];

            //get first child...
            var childNode = parentNode.children.view()[0];

            //get item to select...
            var selectItem = treeview.findByUid(childNode.uid);

            //expand the tree and select the item...
            treeview.expand('.k-item');
            treeview.select(selectItem);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added the databound event (Using MVC Razor) and it does not get fired. I am not binding it via an Ajax call and I think that is why the databound event does not fire.

Comment: Also, please post the code you are using to select the node in the tree view.